# Counting NA's of variables with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to count the NA of a set of variables  with a for loop.

```
confounders<-c("Age", "Sex",  "Race", "education")

missings = list() 
for (var in confounders) { missings[[var]] = with(data_all, sum(is.na(var[[1]])))} 
missings
```

I only get the output zero for every variable, which is incorrect:

```
> missings
$Age
[1] 0

$Sex
[1] 0

$Race
[1] 0

$education
[1] 0


> with(data_all, sum(is.na(education)))
[1] 55
```

Comment: Hi Sasi, to help us give you the best answer possible, please provide some of your data. You can do this with `dput(head(your_data, 10))`. You can then paste the output of this function into your question marked as _code_.

Comment: In R you can check the entire data frame for `NA`s and calculate the `colSums`, try `colSums(is.na(data_all[confounders]))` or even `colSums(is.na(data_all))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell R to evaluate `var` a variable, not as a string (e.g. Age, not "Age"). You can do this with `get(eval())`

```
data_all=data.frame(Age=c(34,40,50,40),Sex=c("F","M","M","F"), Race=c(NA,NA,NA,NA), education=c("high","low","low",NA))

confounders<-c("Age", "Sex","Race", "education")

missings = list() 
for (var in confounders) { 
    missings[[var]] = with(data_all, sum(is.na(get(eval(var)))))
} 
missings
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
confounders<-c("Age", "Sex",  "Race", "education")

missings = list() 
for (var in confounders) { 
             missings[[var]] = sum(is.na(data_all[[var]])) 
             } 
missings
```